# Symfony2 - how can I get Entity Object based on custom query?

Tags: mysql, orm, symfony, doctrine-orm, php-5.3

this is my custome query:

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT max(d.id) FROM MyBundle:DBTableEntity d ");
$max_incoming_id = $query->execute();
```

I want it to return the Entity Object, just like this one below:

```
$EntityObj = $resource->getRepository("MyBundle:DBTableEntity")->findAll();
```

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Solution: 
$query = $resource->createQuery("SELECT d FROM MyBundle:MyEntity d where d.id > 5); 
$entities = $query->execute(); 

foreach ($entities as $i=>$entity): 

//get entity's ID 
$entity->getId(); 

endforeach; 

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
$EntityObjects = $resource->getRepository('MyBundle:DBTableEntity')
                         ->createQuery()
                         ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                         ->getResult();

$EntityObject = array_pop($EntityObjects);
```

Comment: I've found the solution, its simple with foreach loop:

    $query = $resource->createQuery("SELECT d FROM MyBundle:MyEntity d where d.id > 5);
    $entities = $query->execute(); 

    foreach ($entities as $i=>$entity):

      //get entity's ID
      $entity->getId();

    endforeach;

That's it!

Comment: I just ran your code and realized getRepository doesn't contain any CreateQuery() method

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT s FROM BundleName:EntityClass s where s.field1 = %d and s.field2=%d", $field1, $field2);
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$queryObj = $em->createQuery($query);
$entities = $queryObj->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

With excute you receive a array of results (entities).

so you can do $entities = $query.excute();

return $entities[0]; //this is if you have one result;

array_pop($entities) will not work this gives a error in symfony 2.6

Answer (score 0):

I think you will like this style:

```
$EntityObj = $resource->getRepository("MyBundle:DBTableEntity")
                      ->findOneBy(array(), array('id' => 'DESC'));
```

:)